# Update rows with min value in a group on MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following statement for Select. Value of the [Flag] has been defaulted to 'No'

```
select t.[Id], t.[Name], t.[NRIC], t.[Flag], t.[Hierarchy], t.[LoadDt] 
from [EmployeeMaster] t
inner join (
select ID, LoadDt, Min(Hierarchy) As MinHierarchy
from [EmployeeMaster]
group by ID, LoadDt
) s on t.[ID] = s.[ID] and t.[Hierarchy] = s.[MinHierarchy]
```

After this, i need to update all the results of the above select statement with a

```
update [EmployeeMaster] set [EmployeeMaster].[Flag] = 'Yes'
```

How can i combine this into 1 query in MS ACCSS VBA script?

Basically what i wanted to achieve is that given an example of the following EmployeeMaster table:

```
ID | Name | NRIC | Flag | Hierarchy | LoadDt 
001| ABCD | ZZZZ |  NO  |     6     | 31/1/2017 
001| ABCD | ZZZZ |  NO  |     5     | 31/1/2017 
001| ABCD | ZZZZ |  NO  |     1     | 31/1/2017 
002| WXYZ | YYYY |  NO  |     9     | 31/1/2017 
002| WXYZ | YYYY |  NO  |     8     | 31/1/2017
```

I want to be able to achieve the output of:

```
ID | Name | NRIC | Flag | Hierarchy | LoadDt
001| ABCD | ZZZZ |  NO  |     6     | 31/1/2017 
001| ABCD | ZZZZ |  NO  |     5     | 31/1/2017
001| ABCD | ZZZZ |  Yes |     1     | 31/1/2017
002| WXYZ | YYYY |  NO  |     9     | 31/1/2017
002| WXYZ | YYYY |  Yes |     8     | 31/1/2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In access, you can't use aggregates in update statement because it'll produce the below error:

> Operation must use an updatable query.

Instead use simple self join to find the row with min Hierarchy for each id and then do the update.

Try this:

```
UPDATE [EmployeeMaster] t
left join [EmployeeMaster] s
on t.[ID] = s.[ID] and t.[Hierarchy] > s.[Hierarchy]
SET t.[Flag] = 'Yes'
where s.[ID] is null
```